# Why does emerging fail?

Tags: linux, gentoo, portage

Running `emerge sys-kernel/gentoo-sources` fails due to `Failed to install sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16`, but both the command output and the mentioned log file don't contain any information afaik:

```
# emerge sys-kernel/gentoo-sources

 * IMPORTANT: 8 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.

Calculating dependencies... done!

>>> Verifying ebuild manifests

>>> Emerging (1 of 1) sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16::gentoo
 * linux-4.9.tar.xz SHA256 SHA512 WHIRLPOOL size ;-) ...                                                                                                                  [ ok ]
 * genpatches-4.9-18.base.tar.xz SHA256 SHA512 WHIRLPOOL size ;-) ...                                                                                                     [ ok ]
 * genpatches-4.9-18.extras.tar.xz SHA256 SHA512 WHIRLPOOL size ;-) ...                                                                                                   [ ok ]
>>> Preparing to unpack ...
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking linux-4.9.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.9-18.base.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/patches
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.9-18.extras.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/patches
 * Excluding Patch #5000_enable-additional-cpu-optimizations-for-gcc.patch ...                                                                                            [ ok ]
 * Applying 1000_linux-4.9.1.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1001_linux-4.9.2.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1002_linux-4.9.3.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1003_linux-4.9.4.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1004_linux-4.9.5.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1005_linux-4.9.6.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1006_linux-4.9.7.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1007_linux-4.9.8.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1008_linux-4.9.9.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1009_linux-4.9.10.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1010_linux-4.9.11.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1011_linux-4.9.12.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1012_linux-4.9.13.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1013_linux-4.9.14.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1014_linux-4.9.15.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1015_linux-4.9.16.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1500_XATTR_USER_PREFIX.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                        [ ok ]
 * Applying 1510_fs-enable-link-security-restrictions-by-default.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                          [ ok ]
 * Applying 2300_enable-poweroff-on-Mac-Pro-11.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                            [ ok ]
 * Applying 2900_dev-root-proc-mount-fix.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                  [ ok ]
 * Applying 4200_fbcondecor.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                               [ ok ]
 * Applying 4400_alpha-sysctl-uac.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                         [ ok ]
 * Applying 4567_distro-Gentoo-Kconfig.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                    [ ok ]
>>> Source unpacked in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source compiled.
>>> Test phase [not enabled]: sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16

>>> Install gentoo-sources-4.9.16 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/image/ category sys-kernel
>>> Copying sources ...
>>> Completed installing gentoo-sources-4.9.16 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/image/

 * Final size of build directory: 0 KiB
 * Final size of installed tree: 771620 KiB

ecompressdir: bzip2 -9 /usr/share/doc

>>> Installing (1 of 1) sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16::gentoo

 * IMPORTANT: 8 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.

Calculating dependencies... done!

>>> Verifying ebuild manifests

>>> Emerging (1 of 1) sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16::gentoo
 * linux-4.9.tar.xz SHA256 SHA512 WHIRLPOOL size ;-) ...                                                                                                                  [ ok ]
 * genpatches-4.9-18.base.tar.xz SHA256 SHA512 WHIRLPOOL size ;-) ...                                                                                                     [ ok ]
 * genpatches-4.9-18.extras.tar.xz SHA256 SHA512 WHIRLPOOL size ;-) ...                                                                                                   [ ok ]
>>> Preparing to unpack ...
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking linux-4.9.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.9-18.base.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/patches
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.9-18.extras.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/patches
 * Excluding Patch #5000_enable-additional-cpu-optimizations-for-gcc.patch ...                                                                                            [ ok ]
 * Applying 1000_linux-4.9.1.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1001_linux-4.9.2.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1002_linux-4.9.3.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1003_linux-4.9.4.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1004_linux-4.9.5.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1005_linux-4.9.6.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1006_linux-4.9.7.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1007_linux-4.9.8.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1008_linux-4.9.9.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
 * Applying 1009_linux-4.9.10.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1010_linux-4.9.11.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1011_linux-4.9.12.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1012_linux-4.9.13.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1013_linux-4.9.14.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1014_linux-4.9.15.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1015_linux-4.9.16.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                             [ ok ]
 * Applying 1500_XATTR_USER_PREFIX.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                        [ ok ]
 * Applying 1510_fs-enable-link-security-restrictions-by-default.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                          [ ok ]
 * Applying 2300_enable-poweroff-on-Mac-Pro-11.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                            [ ok ]
 * Applying 2900_dev-root-proc-mount-fix.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                  [ ok ]
 * Applying 4200_fbcondecor.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                               [ ok ]
 * Applying 4400_alpha-sysctl-uac.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                         [ ok ]
 * Applying 4567_distro-Gentoo-Kconfig.patch (-p1) ...                                                                                                                    [ ok ]
>>> Source unpacked in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source compiled.
>>> Test phase [not enabled]: sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16

>>> Install gentoo-sources-4.9.16 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/image/ category sys-kernel
>>> Copying sources ...
>>> Completed installing gentoo-sources-4.9.16 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/image/

 * Final size of build directory: 0 KiB
 * Final size of installed tree: 771620 KiB

ecompressdir: bzip2 -9 /usr/share/doc

>>> Installing (1 of 1) sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16::gentoo

>>> Failed to install sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/temp/build.log'

 * GNU info directory index is up-to-date.

 * IMPORTANT: 8 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.

# less /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/temp/build.log
 * Package:    sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16
 * Repository: gentoo
 * Maintainer: kernel@gentoo.org
 * USE:        abi_ppc_32 elibc_glibc kernel_linux ppc userland_GNU
 * FEATURES:   preserve-libs sandbox userpriv usersandbox
>>> Preparing to unpack ...
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking linux-4.9.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.9-18.base.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/patches
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.9-18.extras.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/patches
 * Excluding Patch #5000_enable-additional-cpu-optimizations-for-gcc.patch ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1000_linux-4.9.1.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1001_linux-4.9.2.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1002_linux-4.9.3.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1003_linux-4.9.4.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1004_linux-4.9.5.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1005_linux-4.9.6.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1006_linux-4.9.7.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1007_linux-4.9.8.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1008_linux-4.9.9.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1009_linux-4.9.10.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1010_linux-4.9.11.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1011_linux-4.9.12.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1012_linux-4.9.13.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1013_linux-4.9.14.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1014_linux-4.9.15.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1015_linux-4.9.16.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1500_XATTR_USER_PREFIX.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 1510_fs-enable-link-security-restrictions-by-default.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 2300_enable-poweroff-on-Mac-Pro-11.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 2900_dev-root-proc-mount-fix.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 4200_fbcondecor.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 4400_alpha-sysctl-uac.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
 * Applying 4567_distro-Gentoo-Kconfig.patch (-p1) ...
 [ ok ]
>>> Source unpacked in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/work/linux-4.9.16-gentoo ...
>>> Source compiled.
>>> Test phase [not enabled]: sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16

>>> Install gentoo-sources-4.9.16 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/image/ category sys-kernel
>>> Copying sources ...
>>> Completed installing gentoo-sources-4.9.16 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16/image/

 * Final size of build directory: 0 KiB
 * Final size of installed tree: 771620 KiB

ecompressdir: bzip2 -9 /usr/share/doc
```

`genkernel all` fails due to `* ERROR: Kernel Makefile (/usr/src/linux/Makefile) missing.  Maybe re-install the kernel sources.` which makes it pretty clear for me that the installation really didn't work, but that might still be not the case for a reason I don't see.

I'm using the minimal ppc32 live media 20140713 on an iMac G4 PowerMac6,1

Comment: It doesn't say the install didn't work. Pretty sure if you went to /usrc/src/linux and ran 'make menuconfig' it'll configure correctly, and then you could run make all, and it'd make correctly too. The error is that the Makefile is missing.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I can't image how `make` should work without `Makefile`. After adding more swap through a loop device the installation succeeded and `genkernel all` find the kernel source.

Answer (score 1):

The failure occured because the `emerge` process was killed by the out-of-memory (OOM) killer by the kernel. One can check `dmesg` for confirmation.

I requested improvement of the feedback of `emerge` at https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=620938.

Comment: It can't report it was killed by OOM, as it doesn't know, because it's dead... I believe if you ran emerge -v it'd show you the output more verbosely, including the OOM kicking in.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Since it doesn't die without any feedback and is still able to print `>>> Failed to install sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.9.16` the `emerge` process which has been killed is most likely a child process with the same name. The killing is such an important event that it should be shown to the user also without `-v`.